# sys.argv жрёт кавычки при обработке

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Пытаюсь реализовать команду **grep** в python.
Программа должна брать аргументы при иницализации, например
`python grep.py something -v file.txt`. Я это делаю благодаря библиотеке `sys`, а точнее `sys.args`

Также данная программа должна поддерживать регулярные выражения, которые помещаются в двойные кавычки `python grep.py "regex" file.txt`. 
Но при иницализации двойные ковычки, с двух стороно у аргументов слетают, оставляя их голыми. Единственное решение, которое я нашёл это ставить по три кавычки вокруг регулярного выражения `python grep.py """regex""" file.txt`.

Подскажите как можно это обойти.

Comment: Это не sys.argv их жрёт, а cmd.

Comment: А как экранировать кавычки используя cmd?

Comment: python grep.py \"regex\" file.txt